# react-testing-library + material-ui error: Element type is invalid:

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am having an error with rendering a component in the react unit test.
I have tried the same with enzyme gives the same error only for mount method.

The error message is:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

> The above error occurred in the  component:
> in div (created by Header)
> in li (created by ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
> in ForwardRef(ButtonBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)) (created by ForwardRef(ListItem))
> in ForwardRef(ListItem) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ListItem)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ListItem)) (created by ForwardRef(MenuItem))
> in ForwardRef(MenuItem) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(MenuItem)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(MenuItem)) (created by Header)
> in ul (created by ForwardRef(List))
> in ForwardRef(List) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)) (created by ForwardRef(MenuList))
> in ForwardRef(MenuList) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
> in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
> in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Transition)
> in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Grow))
> in ForwardRef(Grow) (created by Unstable_TrapFocus)
> in Unstable_TrapFocus (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
> in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
> in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
> in ForwardRef(Modal) (created by ForwardRef(Popover))
> in ForwardRef(Popover) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
> in ForwardRef(Menu) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)) (created by Header)
> in div (created by Header)
> in div (created by Header)
> in Header (created by Login)
> in div (created by Login)
> in div (created by Login)
> in Login
> in Router
> in GlobalProvider (created by WrapperComponent)
> in WrapperComponent

Heres the code

**1. login.js**

path: src/components/login/index.js

```js
// Login component
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import CustomButton from '../basic-components/button';
import Textfield from '../basic-components/textfield';
import Cross from '../../images/cross-icon.svg';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import ErrorAlert from '../basic-components/snackbar';
import Header from '../basic-components/header';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { useGlobalState, useGlobalDispatch } from '../context/globalContext';
import './style.scss';

const Login = (props) => {
  // const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
  const [isCookieOn,setCookieOn] = useState(false);
  const [errors,setErrors] = useState({errorSeverity:'',openSnackbar:false,msg:'',isError:false}); 
  const history = useHistory();
  const { email } = useGlobalState();
  const globalDispatch = useGlobalDispatch();
  const getVerificationCode = () => {
    if(errors.isError || !email){
      setErrors(errors=>({...errors,openSnackbar:true,errorSeverity:'error',msg:"Please enter valid email"}));
      return
    }
    history.push('/emailverification');
  }
  const setSnackbar = (value) => {
    setErrors(errors=>({...errors,openSnackbar:value}));
  }
  const onEmailChange = debounce((evt) => {
    globalDispatch({type:'setEmail',payload:evt});
    validateEmail(evt);
  },500);

  const validateEmail = (value) => {
    const expression = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(value && !expression.test(value))
      setErrors(errors=>({...errors,isError:true,msg:"Please enter valid email"}));
    else 
      setErrors(errors=>({...errors,isError:false}));
  }

  const setCookie = () => {
    if(!isCookieOn){
      Cookies.set("CookieConsent",true);
      setCookieOn(true);
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    let cookie = Cookies.get("CookieConsent");
    if(cookie){
      setCookieOn(cookie);
    }
    props.setPage(true);
    return () => {
      props.setPage(false);
    }
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Header/>
        <div className="container">
          <div className='images'>
          </div>
          <p className='subtitle'>Welcome!</p>
          <h1 className='head-text'>Please Sign In</h1>
          <div className="inputs">
            <Textfield
              id="email"
              error={errors.isError}
              onChange={(e)=>onEmailChange(e.target.value)}
              label="Enter your email"
              errorMsg={errors.msg}
            />
            <CustomButton classes="code-btn" onClick={getVerificationCode} text="Get Code"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {!isCookieOn && <div className='cookies'>
        <div className='header'>
          <span className='text'>Cookie Talk</span><img src={Cross} className='cross' onClick={setCookie} alt="cancle cookies"/>
        </div>
        <p className='content'>We use cookies to enhance your browsing exeprience. By continuing to browse or closing this banner, you consent to our use of cookies.</p>
      </div>}
      <ErrorAlert
        openSnackbar={errors.openSnackbar} 
        msg={errors.msg} 
        errorSeverity={errors.errorSeverity} 
        setSnackbar={setSnackbar}
        value={email}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function debounce (fn, wait) {
  let t
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(t)
    t = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, arguments), wait)
  }
}

export default Login;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**1. login.spec.js**

path: src/components/login/login.spec.js.

```js
//login.spec.js
import React from 'react';
import Login from './index';
import {renderHook} from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe("Login",()=>{
  it("should render properly",()=>{
    const wrapper = render(<GlobalProvider><Login setPage={jest.fn()}/></GlobalProvider>);
  })
})
```

**1. header.js**

path: src/components/basic-components/header/index.js

```js
//Header component

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useGlobalState,useGlobalDispatch } from '../../context/globalContext';
// import { useProfileState } from '../../context/profileContext';
import {ReactComponent as SearchIcon}  from '../../../images/search-icon.svg';
import './header.scss';
import NavDrawer from '../drawer/drawer';
import {DashboardIcon}  from '../../SvgComponents/dashboard';
import {SupportIcon}  from '../../SvgComponents/support';
import {ProfileIcon}  from '../../SvgComponents/profile';
import {SettingsIcon}  from '../../SvgComponents/settings';
import {ContactsIcon}  from '../../SvgComponents/mycontacts';
import {ReactComponent as SignOut}  from '../../../images/signOut.svg';
import {DashboardMenuIcon} from '../../SvgComponents/dashboardmenu';
import {Link,useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

const Header = () => {
  const { currentProfileImg,activePage,activeRoute } = useGlobalState();
  const [open,setDrawer] = useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const globalDispatch = useGlobalDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const updateNavigation = (route) => {
    globalDispatch({type:'setActiveRoute',payload:route});
    history.push(`/${route}`);
  }
  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setDrawer(state=>!state);
  }
  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <div className="header-container" style={activePage==='dashboard'?{borderBottom:'1px solid #E0E0E0'}:{}}>
        {/* clickable navigation on arrow */}
        //removed some unnecessary code
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={handleClose}
          className='nav-desktop-menu'
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
            <div className={`menu ${activeRoute==='fellowprofile' ? 'active' :''}`} onClick={()=>updateNavigation('fellowprofile')}>
              <ProfileIcon className='nav-icon' isActive={activeRoute==='fellowprofile' ? true :false}/>
              <div className='nav-title'>Profile</div>
            </div>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
            <div className={`menu ${activeRoute==='settings' ? 'active' :''}`}  onClick={()=>updateNavigation('settings')}>
              <SettingsIcon className='nav-icon' isActive={activeRoute==='settings' ? true :false}/>
              <div className='nav-title'>Settings</div>
            </div>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
            <div className='menu'>
              <SignOut className='nav-icon'/>
              <div className='nav-title'>Sign Out</div>
            </div>
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      
      </div>
      <NavDrawer openDrawer={open} toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer} userProfile={currentProfileImg }/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: What is the content of the `./index` file?

Comment: It's the Login component.

Comment: Could you include the filenames and relative paths of each file (`./src/components/index.js`)? It looks like a wrong import statement or something similar.

Comment: Yes. I have edited with the relative paths. Though error shows an import problem when I comment out all the MenuItems from header.js file then the test gets passed, it renders the component correctly. Looks like something wrong with the material component styles.

Comment: If still you are not able to resolve then share the github link and will check the issue there

Comment: Yes. Resolved the issue. The problem is, I was trying the MenuItem to behave as a link and pushing into the react-router history. Changing with the forward ref helped. Here's the link to refer to https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library. Thank you for noticing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, I was trying the MenuItem to behave as a link and pushing a new route into the router history. Changing with the forward ref helped.

Here's the link to refer to https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library. It was about the implementation of MenuItems.